# Find Id of second item in group using MySQL Group By query

Tags: mysql, group-by

We are doing a simple grouping query to find the duplicated add by next set of items inserted into our db table.

```
    SET @old_set_id = 71, @new_set_id = 72;

    SELECT id,
           request_id,
           data_capture_id as temp_id,
           count(data_capture_id ) as item_count 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE request_id= @old_set_id or request_id= @new_set_id 
    GROUP BY data_capture_id
```

Will result in a table like,

```
  id   request_id   temp_id   item_count
 ----------------------------------------
  3       71        2324345      1
  4       71        6786867      2
  8       72        5276345      1
```

For all the duplicates we need the id of the second item in the group that is what is the id of 72 for the duplicate record 6786867? Currently, it is displaying id of the first set.

Comment: use having clause for the item count more than 1

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from this query:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.record_col_1,
    t2.request_id, 
    count(t1.data_capture_id) as item_count
from (
    select id, request_id, data_capture_id, record_col_1
    from my_table
    order by request_id limit 123456789
) t1 
inner join (
    select request_id, record_col_1
    from my_table
    order by request_id limit 123456789
) t2 ON t2.record_col_1 = t1.record_col_1 and t2.request_id > t.request_id
group by t1.record_col_1
having item_count > 1
```

Our first sub-query assures, that data is sorted by `request_id` before we group it. We have this junk `limit 123456789` because by default MySQL ignores sorting in sub-queries (unless we use this hacky limit). And we have another sub-query with sorted data in order to fetch higher `request_id` from a set with the same `record_col_1`. Finally, we collapse data by `record_col_1` and filter only duplicates.

I'm not sure, if it will work, but try it.